# X[:,0] in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given the following line:

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50);
```

What does `X[:, 0], X[:, 1]` mean? In all the examples I've been looking at, I just see `X,y`.

I also don't understand the purpose of `X, y =`.

The output of `X` is below, which includes the `X` and `y` values. Yet `y` itself has a different output & I can't understand where it's used / why?

```
array([[ 1.85219907,  1.10411295],
       [-1.27582283,  7.76448722],
       [ 1.0060939 ,  4.43642592],
       [-1.20998253,  7.83203579],
       [ 1.92461484,  1.06347673],
       [ 2.28565919,  0.79166208],
       [-1.57379043,  2.69773813],
       [ 1.04917913,  4.31668562],
       [-1.07436851,  7.93489945],
       [-1.15872975,  7.97295642]
```

Full script below:

```
#import the required libraries
# - matplotlib is a charting library
# - Seaborn builds on top of Matplotlib and introduces additional plot types. It also makes your traditional Matplotlib plots look a bit prettier.
# - Numpy is numerical Python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
#Generate sample data, with distinct clusters for testing
#n_samples = the number of datapoints, equally split across each clusters
#centers = The number of centers to generate (number of clusters) - a center is the arithmetic mean of all the points belonging to the cluster.
#cluster_std = the standard deviation of the clusters - a quantity expressing by how much the members of a group differ from the mean value for the group (how tight is the cluster going to be)
#random_state = controls the random number generator being used.  If you don't mention the random_state in the code, then whenever you execute your code a new random value is generated and the train and test datasets would have different values each time. However, if you use a particular value for random_state(random_state = 1 or any other value) everytime the result will be same,i.e, same values in train and test datasets.
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4,
                       cluster_std=0.50, random_state=0)
#The below statement, will enable us to visualise matplotlib charts, even in ipython
#Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX
#Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
%pylab
#plot the chart
#s = the sizer of the points.
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50);
```

Comment: RTFM: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Thanks - OK so if it's the start / end of the ndarray, why is it :1? Is it because each sub-array is only 2 elements long?

Comment: Continue reading the docs. `X[:1]` is not the same as `X[:, 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make_blobs generates "isotropic Gaussian blobs" - X is a numpy array with two columns which contain the (x, y) Gaussian coordinates of these points, whereas y contains the list of categories for each.

```
In[1]:  X.shape
Out[1]: (300, 2)
```

X[:, 0] is the numpy coordinates way of selecting every row entry for column 0 - i.e. a single column from the numpy array.

You can see the clusters of coordinates more easily if you plot them. Your code appears to be missing a

```
plt.show()
```

which would display the plot.
[make_blob plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nmjS.png)

If you plot one of these columns against y, you can see more clearly that they're categorised according to their coordinates, but this isn't a particularly useful plot in itself.
[X[:, 0] plotted against y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Fjy.png)

Answer (score 3):

`X` is a 2D numpy array. `X[:,0]` is accessing everything in the first column, and `X[:,1]` is accessing everything in the second column.

In the case of your `plt.scatter` statement, the "x" and "y" of the graph are both from `X`.

`X, y =` simply means that the output of `make_blobs()` has two elements, that are assigned to `X` and `y`. The association with "x" and "y" in the scatterplot is somewhat confusing, due to the names assigned to the variables. "x" and "y" can be any variable, or (as in this case) can be indexed separately from a single 2D numpy array.